# "Assign To Do Item" action is not available in SharePoint 2013 designer workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, tasks

I want to create one SharePoint 2013 designer workflow which should create one task for one user without any outcomes of the task like Approve/Reject. I just want to assign one to-do task so that workflow can wait until status of the task has not changed to "Completed".

I can find "**Assign To Do Item**" action in **SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow** which fulfill my requirement but I can't see same action in **SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow**

Is there any workflow around to achieve same thing with **SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow**?

Comment: The reason for you are unable to see that action in SP2013 designer workflow is that it is available only on the SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform. As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj728659.aspx) MSDN link.

Comment: Don't have much idea about the SP2013 designer workflow but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614606.aspx) link may helpful to you.

Comment: Dear Mr. Users1100, thanks for the information but is there any other way to do so in SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow(I have already asked for work around)

Comment: The simple workaround would be to create a SharePoint 2010 workflow, unless there's a specific reason you're using the 2013 workflow engine.